# JSDoc on Nodejs gives TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, jsdoc3

I would like to generate automatic documentation for my javascript project using JSDoc running on Nodejs. I did the following:

1. Installed Nodejs
2. Installed jsdoc from nodejs as follows: npm install jsdoc

Everything seemed to go well. Then, I run JSDoc on a sample javascript file:

> c:>jsdoc d:\version.js
>
> C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:341
>       packageDocs = new Package(props.packageJson);
>                     ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at Object.module.exports.cli.parseFiles (C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\n ode_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:341:19)
>       at module.exports.cli.main (C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\j sdoc\cli.js:232:14)
>       at Object.module.exports.cli.runCommand (C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\n ode_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:189:5)
>       at C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js:178:13
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jsdoc\ jsdoc.js:180:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

Please note I get this error no matter where I run jsdoc from and no matter which javascript file I use.

Can anyone help?

**Update**
If I delete lines 341-343 in cli.js, everything runs fine. Is it possible that these three lines are particular to a particular (i.e. non-windows) environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the misfortune of installing JSDoc on the morning of June 10, just after I introduced [bug #662](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/662). I fixed the bug later that morning.

The issue is fixed in the most recent version on npm (currently 3.3.0-alpha8).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about case sensitivity.

1. try to copy a file ( /path/to/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/**package.js** -> **package2.js** )
2. try to modify cli.js ( var Package = require('jsdoc/**package**').Package; -> var Package = require('jsdoc/**package2**').Package; )

Good Luck!

Comment: Not quite. The bug was in [Requizzle](https://github.com/hegemonic/requizzle), which JSDoc now uses to meddle with the module-loading process. As a result of the bug, when JSDoc tried to require `jsdoc/package`, it got `node_modules/jsdoc/package.json` instead of `node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/package.js`.